# Pandas custom aggregate function with condition on group, is it possible?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
  [{'price': 22, 'weight': 1, 'product': 'banana', },
  {'price': 20, 'weight': 2, 'product': 'apple', },
  {'price': 18, 'weight': 2, 'product': 'car', },
  {'price': 100, 'weight': 1, 'product': 'toy', },
  {'price': 27, 'weight': 1, 'product': 'computer', },
  {'price': 200, 'weight': 1, 'product': 'book', },
  {'price': 200.5, 'weight': 3, 'product': 'mouse', },
  {'price': 202, 'weight': 3, 'product': 'door', },]
)
```

What I have to do is to group by contiguous prices where the difference between them is less than a threshold (say 2.0) or not. After that I have to apply the following aggregations ONLY on the group 'less than threshold', otherwise the group should not be aggregated:

1. `price` should be the weighted average between `price` and `weight`
2. `weight` should be the maximum value
3. `product` should be string concatenation

What I did so far (step by step):

1. I sorted the dataframe by prices in ascending order (to get the contiguous values)

```
df.sort_values(by=['price'], inplace=True)
```

```
    price  weight   product
2   18.0       2       car
1   20.0       2     apple
0   22.0       1    banana
4   27.0       1  computer
3  100.0       1       toy
5  200.0       1      book
6  200.5       3     mouse
7  202.0       3      door
```

2. Got the difference between the prices in ascesding and descending order to detect the contiguous prices

```
df['asc_diff'] = df['price'].diff(periods=1)
df['desc_diff'] = df['price'].diff(periods=-1).abs()
```

```
    price  weight   product  asc_diff  desc_diff
2   18.0       2       car       NaN        2.0
1   20.0       2     apple       2.0        2.0
0   22.0       1    banana       2.0        5.0
4   27.0       1  computer       5.0       73.0
3  100.0       1       toy      73.0      100.0
5  200.0       1      book     100.0        0.5
6  200.5       3     mouse       0.5        1.5
7  202.0       3      door       1.5        NaN
```

3. Combined `asc_diff` and `desc_diff` columns to remove `NaN` and create the continous regions

```
df['asc_diff'] = df['asc_diff'].combine_first(df['desc_diff'])
df['asc_diff'] = df[['asc_diff', 'desc_diff']].min(axis=1).abs()
df['asc_diff'] = df['asc_diff'] <= 2.0
df = df.drop(columns=['desc_diff'])
```

```
    price  weight   product  asc_diff
2   18.0       2       car      True
1   20.0       2     apple      True
0   22.0       1    banana      True
4   27.0       1  computer     False
3  100.0       1       toy     False
5  200.0       1      book      True
6  200.5       3     mouse      True
7  202.0       3      door      True
```

4. Created the groups

```
g = df.groupby((df['asc_diff'].shift() != df['asc_diff']).cumsum())
for k, v in g:
    print(f'[group {k}]')
    print(v)
```

```
[group 1]
   price  weight product  asc_diff
2   18.0       2     car      True
1   20.0       2   apple      True
0   22.0       1  banana      True
[group 2]
   price  weight   product  asc_diff
4   27.0       1  computer     False
3  100.0       1       toy     False
[group 3]
   price  weight product  asc_diff
5  200.0       1    book      True
6  200.5       3   mouse      True
7  202.0       3    door      True
```

So far so good, but when I had to aggregate comes the problems:

```
def product_join(x):
    return ' '.join(x)
g.agg({'weight': 'max', 'product': product_join})
```

```
           weight           product
asc_diff                          
1              2  car apple banana
2              1      computer toy
3              3   book mouse door
```

The problems:

- only group 1 and 3 should be aggregated (but in the code it applys to all groups)
- even using a custom function (e.g. product_join) I have no access to other columns values, so that I can get the weighted average prices for example.

What I want to accomplish:

- Aggregate only groups 1 and 3 (where `asc_diff` is true) and keep group 2 intact
- in `price` aggregate function I needed a function to access two columns (i.e. `price` and `weight`) to get the weighted average value

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have 20,22,24, should they be grouped together? since the difference between 20 and 24 is 4.

Comment: Yes, they should be grouped together, since they are linked to each other by a difference of 2 (less or equal to the threshold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting it right, you want to aggregate only the groups where all of the values in the `asc_diff` column are `True`. The other groups (`asc_diff == False`), should not be changed.

If that's the case, starting off from what you've done so far, the solution is straightforward. You only need to create a custom apply function that will do the work for you based on the conditions you define. The custom apply function would be like this:

```py
def custom_apply(df):
    if df['asc_diff'].all() == False:
        df = df.set_index('asc_diff')
        return df[['price', 'weight', 'product']]
    
    def wavg(x): return np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, "weight"])

    df1 = df.groupby('asc_diff').agg({'price': wavg, 'weight': 'max'})
    df2 = df.groupby('asc_diff').agg({'product': ' '.join})
    return pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

The main tweaks of this function are the following:

1. You need to check the values of the column `asc_diff`. If all of them are `False` you just return the dataframe with the columns you want.
2. Use a custom function to calculate your weighted price (`wavg`)
3. Calculate your aggregations and concatenate them.

Then, you just need to apply this function in your grouped dataframe like this:

```py
print(g.apply(custom_apply).droplevel(1))
```

The result will be:

```
               price  weight           product
asc_diff                                      
1          19.600000       2  car apple banana
2          27.000000       1          computer
2         100.000000       1               toy
3         201.071429       3   book mouse door
```

Comment: Thanks for the other alternatives for enriching the solution, but I'll go with this one as it uses only pandas and is more didatic.

Answer (score 2):

This builds off @Panwen Wang's solution, and sticking with Pandas:

Get the contiguous rows via cumsum and diff :

```
temp = (df
        .sort_values('price')
        .assign(group = lambda df: df.price.diff().gt(2).cumsum())
       )

temp

   price  weight   product  group
2   18.0       2       car      0
1   20.0       2     apple      0
0   22.0       1    banana      0
4   27.0       1  computer      1
3  100.0       1       toy      2
5  200.0       1      book      3
6  200.5       3     mouse      3
7  202.0       3      door      3
```

Create a custom function to get the weighted mean (you can alternatively use np.average, I'm only trying to avoid the apply function):

```
def weighted_mean(df, column_to_average, weights, by):
     df = df.copy()
     df = df.set_index(by)
     numerator = df[column_to_average].mul(df[weights]).sum(level=by)
     denominator = df[weights].sum(level=by)
     return numerator/denominator
```

Compute the results:

```
(temp
 .assign(price = lambda df: df.group.map(weighted_mean))
 .groupby('group')
 .agg(price=('price','first'), 
      weight=('weight','max'), 
      product=('product', ' '.join))
 )
 
            price  weight           product
group                                      
0       19.600000       2  car apple banana
1       27.000000       1          computer
2      100.000000       1               toy
3      201.071429       3   book mouse door
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will incorporate some parts of your solution to my step-by-step, specially the contiguous rows approach, it's elegant and reduces lines of code!

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to do it with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), which is backended by pandas, but implemented the `dplyr` syntax in R:

##### Create the groups

```py
>>> from datar.all import (
...     f, tribble, arrange, lag, if_else, is_na, 
...     group_by, mutate, summarise, select,
...     cur_group_id, cumsum, weighted_mean, max, paste
... )
[2021-06-25 13:35:20][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "max" has been overriden by datar.
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.price, f.weight, f.product, 
...     22,      1,        'banana',
...     20,      2,        'apple',
...     18,      2,        'car',
...     100,     1,        'toy',
...     27,      1,        'computer',
...     200,     1,        'book',
...     200.5,   3,        'mouse',
...     202,     3,        'door', 
... )
>>> 
>>> df = df >> \
...     arrange(f.price) >> \
...     mutate(
...         price_diff=f.price - lag(f.price),
...         group_flag=f.price_diff > 2.0,
...         group=cumsum(f.group_flag)
...     ) >> \
...     group_by(f.group)
>>> df
      price  weight   product  price_diff  group_flag   group
  <float64> <int64>  <object>   <float64>      <bool> <int64>
0      18.0       2       car         NaN       False       0
1      20.0       2     apple         2.0       False       0
2      22.0       1    banana         2.0       False       0
3      27.0       1  computer         5.0        True       1
4     100.0       1       toy        73.0        True       2
5     200.0       1      book       100.0        True       3
6     200.5       3     mouse         0.5       False       3
7     202.0       3      door         1.5       False       3

[Groups: group (n=4)]
```

The idea is pretty much like what you did. We first sorted the df by `price` and created a `price_diff` column with the difference between current price and price in the previous row.
Then with that difference, we can tell when rows should be separate (`group_flag`).

Notice that it's not the grouping flag, it's just tell us whether we should put current rows in a separate group. If you look at row#5, it should be grouped with rows#6/7, but `True` here tells us it should be separated with row#4. The `False`s of rows#6/7 are telling no to separate them from row#5.

Then by `cumsum` them, we can easily get the group ids.

##### Do the aggregation

```py
>>> df >> \
...     # don't include the intermediate columns
...     select(~f.price_diff, ~f.group_flag) >> \
...     summarise(
...         price=weighted_mean(f.price, f.weight),
...         weight=max(f.weight),
...         product=paste(f.product, collapse=' ')
...     )
    group       price  weight           product
  <int64>   <float64> <int64>          <object>
0       0   19.600000       2  car apple banana
1       1   27.000000       1          computer
2       2  100.000000       1               toy
3       3  201.071429       3   book mouse door
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this package, I'll take a look at it as it seems to be as useful as pandas. But I'll definitely take some time to understand its syntax :D